# returning the full row of a grouped by query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that essentially tries to get the max serial value for each distinct `other_field` (simplified example below).

there are a few fields you need to know about

```
    ID text
    ser serial
    other_field text
```

For each distinct `other_field` I want to find the full row with the largest serial value

I basically want to return the whole row but end up having to join on the same table to retrieve what I want (since the group by clause is generally so restrictive). The query I use below

```sql
    SELECT small_q.id FROM (
        SELECT id, MAX(ser) as serial FROM table_name GROUP BY other_field
    ) max_q JOIN table_name full_t ON small_q.serial = max_q.serial
```

Is there any way for me to avoid having to join on the same table?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: A little bit too simplified? Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: very cool link @jarlh i've updated the question a bit to get a better answer

Comment: There is an entire tag for these kinds of questions - `[greatest-n-per-group]`.

Comment: I can never quite find the tag to best describe my problem, but many thanks for letting me know @Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy answer would be to use windowing function:

```sql
SELECT main.* FROM (
        SELECT *, MAX(ser) over (partition by other_field) as serial FROM table_name
    ) main where main.ser=main.serial
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for only one row per `other_field`, I strongly advocate `distinct on` in Postgres:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (other_field) t.id
FROM table_name t
ORDER BY other_field, ser DESC ;
```

In Postgres, `DISTINCT ON` usually has better performance characteristics than other ways of accomplishing the same thing.

Comment: apologies for bumping this comment, but after a year of accepting the other answer this turns out to be an extremely effective method with much less cognitive complexity. I definitely favour it over the window function for this use case, many thanks :)

Comment: @Deepak is usually preferred in Postgres.  As the OP you can accept whichever answer you wish -- I would only recommend changing if you have a good reason, but you seem to have a good reason.